# How to connect MATLAB and React?

Tags: c, reactjs, matlab

I am using React, and for a project I need access to MATLAB output. How is the connection between MATLAB and React possible?
Is it possible to call the code written in C in React, or in other words, use the function written in C in React?

The main purpose is the connection between MATLAB and React.

There are a number of points.  I want the user to be able to add new points to them.  Then compute a function for their interpolation

Comment: What kind of MATLAB code would you like to call? What do you want to do with the output? Some more detail might help a potential answerer.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/336499-matlab-and-new-web-technologies

Comment: There are a number of points.  I want the user to be able to add new points to them.  Then compute a function for their interpolation

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to call the code written in C in React, or in other words, use the function written in C in React?

Yes, it is possible. You can compile your function code written in C or C++ to WebAssembly file. You are able then to import such function and pass init values from React to it.

More about creating WebAssembly file from C: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/C_to_wasm

So in theory, if you can convert you MatLab function to C and then from C to WebAssebly you should be able to use Matlab functions inside React.